# Consistency of data

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, data-analysis

In particle physics, what factors do we consider to conclude that the measurements done by two different experiments are consistent with each other? 
(You may even explain the concept with an example)

Comment: You mean like the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J/psi_meson ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will give an example of the recent measurement of the [mass of the Higgs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.07589;) by two different experiments, ATLAS and CMS,

[image: higgsm]

There are several channels from which the mass has  been measured individually. The error  bars are one standard deviation , showing the combined statistical and systematic error for each channel for each experiment, and the combined values , with smaller errors. To combine  different experiment data sets one uses [statistics tools](https://www.princeton.edu/%7Ecap/AEESP_Statchap_Peters.pdf) .

[The link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.07589;) uses more sophisticated tools  to reduce the error in the mass of the Higgs.

In particle physics results are considered consistent if within less than four standard deviations difference between the independent experimental values. From five standard deviations one talks of discrepancy that has to he explained ( or discovery). This rule holds for the table above, as the largest difference is in the gamma channel which differs by Atlas errors by ~2.5 sigma and thus is considered consistent.

Answer (score 1):

I do a measurement and get a result. If I used my result to predict the results of your experiment, would I predict the same result (within our error margins) you got or something different?

If I do an experiment where I measure the acceleration due to gravity and use that to estimate that the mass of the Earth is $6\times 10^{24} \pm 0.5\times 10^{24}\ {\rm kg}$, and you do an experiment where you measure the Earth's orbit and the sun's mass and estimate that the mass of the earth is $5.9\times 10^{24} \pm 0.1\times 10^{24}\ {\rm kg}$, then our results are consistent.

If you had the same estimate as above, but I estimated the mass of the Earth to be  $6.8\times 10^{24} \pm 0.5\times 10^{24}\ {\rm kg}$, then those wouldn't be consistent.